# Rebasing local Git branch before push to remote

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-push

Remotes: **origin**

```
$ git branch
* master

$ git checkout -b "new_feature"
```

Now I do couple of commits on "new_feature" branch and want to push it to **origin** after updating it.

```
$ git branch
master
* new _feature

$ git pull --rebase origin new_feature    
$ git push origin new_feature
```

Is this the correct way to update the local branch before pushing to remote?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

The [arguments to `git pull`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) must be an optional remote, and an optional refspec or reference/branch ***on that remote***:

```
git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>…]]
```

`new_feature` won't work because it's a local branch, and additionally, it doesn't make sense for the `rebase`, because you want to pass a revision to `rebase` the branch `new_feature` ***on top of***. If you have `new_feature` checked out, then it's understood/implicit that that's the branch you want to `rebase`, that's how `rebase` normally works.

Comment: I fail to understand this. My understanding is that , since I have to push new_feature branch to remote , I want to update new_feature before pushing. So now I am currently working on new_feature branch. Then how gir pull --rebase origin master will update "new_feature" ? That will update master branch correct ? Sorry for this . But some reason I am not getting this last part.

Comment: You'll have to clarify your question. Were you trying to update `new_feature` with changes to it from `origin`? Or were you trying to update it with changes made to `master` in `origin`?

Answer (score 3):

After creating your "new_feature" branch the you will have a state like

```
o   <master> <origin/master> <new_feature>  most recent commit
|
...
```

Then, after commiting your changes to your local branch your repository will look like

```
o   <new_feature>   your last commit
|
o   your first commit
|
o   <master> <origin/master>    most recent commit
|
...
```

Doing a

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

, as Cupcake suggests, you will end with

```
o   <new_feature>   your last commit
|
o   your first commit
|
o   <origin/master> something meanwhile commited on remote master
|
o   <master>    most recent commit
|
...
```

your changes rebased on top of "origin/master". These are not your original commits but commits changed to fit on the "new" "origin/master".

Doing rebase you can get merge conflicts, because changes made on remote master may conflict with your changes.

But because "new_feature" is now "on top of" "origin/master" you can do a push to the remote master.

This will also move the tag "origin/master" to the level of "new_feature". If you also want to have your local "master" on track, you have then to check it out and do a merge with "origin/master".